# C# Json Anonymous Type to include list of values

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, anonymous-types

I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 application and a method within a controller which returns a JsonResult. Inside the method, a variable called `myData` retrieves an `IList<customer>`.

The customer object is like this:

```
public class customer
{
    public int custId {get; set;}
    public string custName {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<address> addresses{ get; set; }
}
```

I then create an anonymous type and return it as Json. See below.

```
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    var myData = _myService.GetAll().Select(x => new
    {
        custId = x.custId,
        custName = x.custName
    }).ToList();

    return Json(myData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This works, however, my problem is that inside my anonymous type, I also need to reference the `addresses` collection. The `address` class looks like this:

```
public class address
{
    public int addressId {get; set;}
    public int custId {get; set;}
    public string addressName {get; set;}
    public virtual customer cust { get; set; }
}
```

What I need to do within my anonymous type is to get the customers `addressName`, of which there could be as many as three.

So, something like this:

```
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    var myData = _myService.GetAll().Select(x => new
    {
        custId = x.custId,
        custName = x.custName,
        custAddresses = x.addresses.All().addressName
    }).ToList();

    return Json(myData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Obviously trying to get all the customer address names like this doesn't work, and this is where i'm stuck.

Could anyone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `x.addresses.Select(address => address.addressName)`?

Comment: var allAddresses = IEnumerable<Address>() // Your addresses function here; Into myData new { custAddresses = allAddresses }.ToList(); return Json(myData)

Comment: @Jordi this code does not compile.

Comment: It's a idea only , basically he have to put into the new anonymous Json custAddresses = allAddresses with the collection of address which he have.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, no idea why I didn't do that in the first place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x.addresses.Select(address => address.addressName).ToList()
```

This will give you a list of address names. You can keep it as a list, create a single string out of it with `String.Join`, or reduce to a sublist, depending on your needs.